# How can I pass an argument while transitioning to the UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

Okay so I have my CollectionViewController, on click of which I transition to my UIPageViewController like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let selectedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: PhotoCell.self), for: indexPath ) as? PhotoCell
        else { fatalError("unexpected cell in collection view") }

    let asset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController( PageViewController() , animated: true)
}
```

In my PageViewController:

```
override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation, options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey : Any]? = nil) {
    super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: navigationOrientation, options: nil)
    delegate = self
    dataSource = self
    edgesForExtendedLayout = []

    setViewControllers([allDetailedViewControllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have a setViewControllers method where I'm setting the first of allDetailedViewControllers[0]. My question being, how can I on the click of the collectionView cell pass the appropriate cell index or any argument into the page viewcontroller so I can use setViewControllers with the desired index.
For eg: `setViewControllers([allDetailedViewControllers[desiredIndex/argument]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`

As per my knowledge the UIPageController does not have an override init(with argument: argumentType) method which is why im stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any methods/set any properties to the `pageViewController` before pushing.

For example, write this function in your `PageViewController`:

```
func doWhateverYouWant(_ arg:YourArgType)
{
    //do whatever you want with your args
    setViewControllers([allDetailedViewControllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

To push it, write in this away:

```
let pageViewController = PageViewController()
pageViewController.doWhateverYouWant(yourArgs)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController( pageViewController , animated: true)
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Thank you!